# "Reinitialize" a sharedInstance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, object, shared

This may sound wierd.

**Scenario**

Implementing AFOauthClient

I created a subclass and created a shared instance with my baseurl and all
as

```
+ (GYMAFOAuthClient *)sharedClient {
    static GYMAFOAuthClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kServer_Address"]];
        if (url==nil) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Required" message:@"Please enter the required fields in the settings page of the application" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
        }
        else
        {
             _sharedClient = [GYMAFOAuthClient clientWithBaseURL:url clientID:kClientID secret:kClientSecret];
        }       
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}
```

Works perfectly.

**But**

now i have a requirement to switch to other server and as i am using dispatch_once method reinitializing is a trouble.How can i assign a new url and make my shared instance with the baseurl as new url.

**What i tried:**

I am using settings bundle for the purpose I have the url in my user-defaults now just need to create a client and start getting responses.How can i achieve it?

**Clarification:**

Change the server ...means i have 5 VC and one login VC and all the server base url is the same until the user go and edit the settings page .so that means after settings edit user have to start application relogin and then get all services.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously a shared/singleton instance was not the correct architecture for your problem. I'd start by trying to get rid of the use of `sharedClient` here and just pass around an instance to things that need it. That way you will be able to destroy it and create a new one when required.

If that's impractical because you've wound your singleton too deeply, then you'll need to modify it so that it is a "has-a" `GYMAFOAuthClient` rather than an "is-a" `GYMAFOAuthClient`. That way you'll be able to reconfigure it.

Comment: Beginner issues.please explain what else to do.I had almost finished everything and so a complete change is a bit of trouble!! But can you guys explain more to help me rewrite?

Comment: @bbum One doubt.If i try this way oauth becomes trouble for me..I set the client header with token i get from login page and hence i designed as a shared/singleton instance .If i make it the other way around how can i manage that?

Answer (score 0):

you can get autorelease object using this code

```
+ (GYMAFOAuthClient *) clientWithURL:(NSURL*) url {

 GYMAFOAuthClient *client = nil;
    if (url==nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Required" message:@"Please enter the required fields in the settings page of the application" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
    }
    else
    {
        client = [GYMAFOAuthClient clientWithBaseURL:url clientID:kClientID secret:kClientSecret];
    }
return client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rob on this however you could also create your url as a property in AFOSharedClient.

Then you can should be able to update it as it's just a pointer to a spot in memory.